# Auto restart a desktop app after windows host reboots

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, desktop

I have a desktop windows app that runs on Win Server 2019 that contains its own scheduler and other controls to configure and run a daily batch processing task and check logging. The host is often patched and then rebooted out of hours so I need a way to restart this app so that its user interface will appear when a specific user logs in (not running detached from desktop). We've attempted various methods to auto restarting it but can't find a way to attach/bind it to the windows desktop so that it appears when the user logs in.

(Yes we know ... it should have been developed as a command line app and run by the Windows scheduler. I didn't write it!)

Comment: Will Task Scheduler not work in this scenario? Registry-based startup app for the specified user?

Comment: No. The key issue is how to bind an app that is auto started to a windows desktop UI. I suspect this is not possible since the windows desktop does not yet exist.  Thanks for your brainstorming.

Comment: We've attempted many different methods including startup via scheduler as the desktop user.  One of us is a senior sw engineer (me), the other a senior systems admin.